# Wrong time from Mysql db when read DateTime with node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, datetime

the problem is that the mysql console shows me the date time as: 2000-01-01 09:10:00
The result in when is: 2000-01-01T08:10:00.000Z
global.time_zone and session.time_zone is set to +00:00 and the server is in Germany.
This is the Node.js code:

```
connection.query('select e.date from events as e', function(err, result){        
    res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
```

When i set the system time to UTC it works fine but it would be better to have a solution that work doesn't care about the systems time_zone.
Any help or idea is appreciated :D

Comment: please see [How do I set the timezone of MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19069310/1118978)

Comment: Thanks for the idea : ) , but sadly I've already read and done this my global- and session timezone are already set to +00:00 so the convert_tz method doesn't change any thing.

Comment: you need to leave your timezone as it is. changing it to UTC would cause much more trouble.

Comment: Then ist works, but could you explain why I can't change it to 00? and doesn't mysql expect a time from this time zone(in my case +01)? so if I want to eject a time from another TZ it needs to be conferted to the TZ of the server?